# Call a method without loading a view in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am currently trying to call a method from my view to change a boolean in my database, the only thing i don't know since i am not really familiar with MVC is that whenever i call my controller method it gives me a blank page. I just want to call the method but stay in the actual view.

Here is the part of code in my view.

```
<td><a href="@Url.Action("PutInBin", "Capture", new { captureId = @Model.Files.Captures.ElementAt(i).Capture_Id })", onclick="DeleteCapture(@(i + 1))">Delete</a></td>
```

And here is the method in my controller

```
public void PutInBin(int captureId)
    {
        QueryCaptureToBin queryCaptureToBin = new QueryCaptureToBin();
        queryCaptureToBin.Capture_Id = captureId;
        client.PlaceCaptureInBin(queryCaptureToBin, userParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Delete",
        "PutInBin", 
        "Capture", 
        new { 
            captureId = Model.Files.Captures.ElementAt(i).Capture_Id 
        },
        new AjaxOptions {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
        }  
    )       
</td>
```

and don't forget to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PutInBin(int captureId)
{
    QueryCaptureToBin queryCaptureToBin = new QueryCaptureToBin();
    queryCaptureToBin.Capture_Id = captureId;
    client.PlaceCaptureInBin(queryCaptureToBin, userParams);
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

and if you wanted to get notification when the delete finishes:

```
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink(
        "Delete",
        "PutInBin", 
        "Capture", 
        new { 
            captureId = Model.Files.Captures.ElementAt(i).Capture_Id 
        },
        new AjaxOptions {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "onDeleteSuccess"
        }
    )       
</td>
```

and then you would have your `onDeleteSuccess` javascript function:

```
var onDeleteSuccess = function(result) {
    // normally the result variable will contain the response
    // from the server but in this case since we returned an EmptyResult
    // don't expect to find anything useful in it.

    alert('The capture was successfully deleted');
};
```

Comment: works! but the table doesn't refreshing automatically. How can I refresh it?

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the page. Please use below java script function. It's same as above  but removed "alert" and used  window.location.reload(true). Use in html or cshtml view. Hats off original owner

---

```
<script>

    var onDeleteSuccess = function(result) {

        // normally the result variable will contain the response
        // from the server but in this case since we returned an EmptyResult
        // don't expect to find anything useful in it.

        window.location.reload(true);

        // alert('The capture was successfully deleted');

    };

 </script>
```